# Second smallest number from different file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to get the second smallest number from another file and two different rows. I've tried it like this:

```
=SMALL('https://test/[file.xlsx]'!)$I$3:$I$27:'https://test/[file.xlsx]'!$I$29:$I$46;2)
```

For some reason this only works when the other file is opened. I've also tried it with the min() function which works perfectly without the other file opened but I can't get the second smallest number.
The excel, where I want to extract the number is connected, updated and status is ok
Is there any workaround or does anyone find a mistake?
Thanks

Comment: Did all cells use the same cell format?

Answer (score 0):

First item is you have an unwanted `)` character in your formula. It is in the first range you specify, after the `.xlsx]'!` and before `$I$3:$I$27`. That alone would make things fail.

That is because you then have `=SMALL('https://test/[file.xlsx]'!)` in which `SMALL` is given no actual address, just a filename with an extra `!` and further, has no parameter to tell it which value to return so even if that ("interestingly" if it did) read the entire file into the function means it still would not know "which-th" value to return.

However, the bigger problem (in the sense that that's likely just a typo, though both kill the formula) is the way you've formed the range for `SMALL` to examine. You clearly do not want cell I28 considered and unfortunately, it is right in the middle. However, you have chosen to give the function a range of the form:

```
A1:A5:A7:A10
```

expecting Excel to grasp you want A1 to A10 except for A6. It does not do that though. It looks at ANY range you enter and builds a "box" of cells that has the upper leftmost cell in it as the start and the lowest rightmost cell as its opposite corner. It includes everything in that "box" in the range it interprets it as. So the above gets you A1:A10 with A6 included. The following:

```
D3:J9:A2:K3:L1:L3
```

gets you the range A2:L9 as that is the smallest "box" of cells that includes those two extremes, the leftmost column being column A and the lowest row number being row 2, so A2 and the rightmost column being column L and the highest row number being row 9 so L9.

To include both ranges and not have unfortunate results due to them being different sizes, you can build the range you desire from the most recent new functions from Excel. Pretty easily, looks like. However, I am not conversant in them yet, just having gotten them and perhaps you don't have them either. So a different way would be the formula:

```
=SMALL(  IFERROR(  INDEX(  ($I$3:$I$27,  $I$29:$I$46),  SEQUENCE(  MAX(  ROWS($I$3:$I$27),  ROWS($I$29:$I$46)  )  ),  1,  {1,2}),  ""),  2)
```

In it, `INDEX` is used to join the two ranges together. Very seldom used, but there if needed is the ability for `INDEX` to be given more than one "Area" and switch between them, or as in the above, be forced to use each. You put the several areas (two in this case) in parentheses to let `INDEX` know they have nothing to do with its other parameters.

To tell it how many rows from each range to use (2nd parameter), you have `ROWS` see how many rows are in each area and then `MAX` to find the biggest of those results. That is then given to `SEQUENCE` so it will use that many rows. This makes sure you get all the rows of the biggest range, rather than cutting some of them off. But it means the shorter areas will be filled in with an error as they do not have anything for the difference in rows. In this case, that's something like 8 rows of errors.

Sadly, that makes the formula choke on itself. So `IFERROR` is used to convert the errors into values that will not choke the formula. But what values? Make them `0`'s and they will compete for being the smallest values... But make them some text value and `SMALL` will ignore them. So the formula makes them the simplest text value, `""`, although almost all other text would be OK. Just no reason for anything else as this result is never seen by anyone!

So now you have a range of two columns and 25 rows, some cells in the second column looking empty, but really having `""` in them. `SMALL` is able to work with a 2-D range, not just a single column or row, so all is good and it find's the second smallest value for you.

Back to the `INDEX` for a moment. I stopped talking about it after the 2nd parameter, the rows value as it took me on the important tangent and pulled me to the end. But there are two other parameters, the column parameter (3rd) and the areas parameter (4th). The column parameter seems easy as there is only one column in each SOURCE range. And that is correct, so it is easy. But you might get the thought that you need a 2 or to indicate it should use columns 1 and 2, some thought along those lines, since there are two columns in the virtual table it makes. But worry not about the output, it is only the source material that matters here, so a 1 is exactly right.

For the areas parameter, you want `INDEX` to return results from BOTH areas... that's actually the whole point. So you need to indicate both areas to it, not just a 1 or a 2. I showed `{1,2}` since that is easy to type and demonstrates a different way to give Excel the info instead of using `SEQUENCE`. And one could argue that `SEQUENCE` is handy for creating the rows parameter because that'd be 43 items, easy to mistype, and definitely obnoxious to type. But it can also take inputs from the outside to build the sequence and that might be of use. Not here, but if you prefer to use it for the 4th parameter, you'd use `SEQUENCE(1,2)`. Another interesting thing about that is that it is not a matter of considering source vs. output. The 2 has to go in its columns parameter since you want two columns out of `INDEX`. Since it must be the columns parameter, you are forced to enter a rows parameter too. That must be a 1 because anything higher tries to create multiple versions of things and leads to strange results in this case, and simply fails in others.

So, to use the formula above, you will need to do TWO things:

1. You must put in the `'https://test/[file.xlsx]'!` string before each of the four places a range is shown. I left it out to make the formula easier to read and understand, but you definitely have to have it!
2. I am using an English language version of Excel so my parameter separator/delimiter is the comma (`,`). You need to change those separators back to your version's semi-colon (`;`).

And then things should work nicely. `SMALL` is one of many functions that will read into a closed file so it should work whether the file is open or not, though performance will almost certainly be much better with it open as every read into a closed file needs to open the file for the one read, then again for the next, and so on. Even if that has been improved over the years, even one opening over a network or the internet will take noticeable time, probably, compared to the file already being open.

As I mentioned above, the new text handling functions WILL build the two ranges into a single range and let you fill the "padding out" cells with anything of your choosing. Worth looking into and editing later, if you have them, but the above should get you going right now.

Finally, if you want an easier to read formula, and one that would be faster for only having to read the ranges once each, you can also wrap it with `LET` and give the ranges names.